# have a better method to run this php?

Tags: php, floating-point

Have another way to run this number generator?
I want all the zeros. for exampe `0.00000000000000000000000009949` instead `9.949E-26`

my code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000000000);
    $myfile = fopen("numbers.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i+= 0.000000000000000000000000000001) {
        $txt = $i.";";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    }
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: why not better use `str_repeat()` or `str_pad()` or `str_fill()` to generate the zeros?

Comment: I've edited the post. i want generate all numbers from 0 to 1 incrementing by 1E-30

Comment: You should read up on floating point math. Specifically, it is not always the case that 1 + 0.000000001 = 1.000000001

Comment: Thing not. maybe use `$i.";\n";` to add a line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i += 0.000000000000000000000000000001) {
    $txt = number_format($i, 30) . ";";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
}
```

This will give you all the zeros or even more, if you like. At least up to some precision, see [Wikipedia - IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for details.

Answer (score 0):

if `PHP_MAX_INTEGER` is not reached you can count down or up  and add from left to a given length filling zeros and `0.` to create the string and to prevent comma operations

like `"0.".str_pad($i,30-strlen($i),'0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."$i\n"`